# Handling soft keyboard and weighted views

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been having this problem for quite a while, but i haven't found any solution to it yet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    layout="@android:layout/list_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/message_et_min_height"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message_edit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/send_message_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/send_button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/send_button_size"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_send_black_24dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using `layout_weight` to size my views. However this creates a problem when the soft keyboard is opened because it resizes the screen and some of my views are squeezed way too much because of the weight parameter([screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M66vT.jpg)). I have tried adjusting the `android:windowSoftInputMode` parameter in my manifest and the results are:

- adjustPan: The `ListView` that is a part of my layout buggs out on older devices, only showing a part of the `ListView`
- adjustNothing: Completely hides the text input part of the layout
- adjustResize: Squeezes some part of the layout (seen on the screenshot)
- adjustUnspecified: Same as adjustResize

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I think weighted view is not required in you case. You can use relative layout and it is easy. and I think your problem will be solved

Comment: Thank you. Post this as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think weighted view is not required in your case. You can use relative layout and it is easy. and I think your problem will be solved.